# Using the youtube_uploader module, how do I upload the video as private, without hacking the module

Tags: hooks, files

I have been able to achieve what I need by changing the module here:

```
function youtube_uploader_get_settings_form() {
  $ret['youtube_uploader_publishing_options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Default privacy options'),
    '#description' => t('More info on !here', array('!here' => l(t('YouTube support page'), 'http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157177'))),
    '#options' => array('public' => t('Public'), 'unlisted' => t('Unlisted'), 'private' => t('Private')),
    '#default_value' => strtolower(variable_get('youtube_uploader_publishing_options', 'unlisted')),
  );
  //Added: 'private' => t('Private') - being the added code.
}
```

How do I achieve this without hacking the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) is what you're looking for. This function, when invoked in any module, will let you modify any form array created/rendered by Drupal's form API. For example, in a module named **mymodule** you could add the following function in **mymodule.module**.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //modify youtube_uploader_get_settings_form to add Private to #options array
  if($form_id == 'youtube_uploader_get_settings_form') {
    $form['youtube_uploader_publishing_options']['#options']['private'] = t('Private');
  }
}
```

---

```
function xxxx_custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'field_ui_field_edit_form' && isset($form['instance']['settings']['youtube_settings']['youtube_uploader_publishing_options'])) {
    $privateOptions = array('public' => t('Public'), 'unlisted' => t('Unlisted'), 'private' => t('Private'));
    $form['instance']['settings']['youtube_settings']['youtube_uploader_publishing_options']['#options'] = $privateOptions;
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  I've used that principal and now I have my Video Uploaded to YouTube with a private setting - without hacking the module.  The code for anyone else looking to do this worked out to be: